# Can't sync xaml files with Git in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am having an issue with Git and Visual Studio and I don't know why, Visual Studio or Git are keeping the changes done to the XAML files when I commit them and change to another branch. What I do is:

- Checkout branch1
- Do my changes to the XAML and CS files
- Commit those changes to branch1
- Checkout branch2
- (Here is the error) The commited changes from XAML files (to branch1) are in this branch2 too, the CS files changes are missing as it should be but the XAML ones don't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The only explanation coming to mind is that the `.xaml` files were never really committed.  If they were untracked, then when you switch branches they would still be there as they were in the other branch.  In any case, using `git status` from the bash at each step you described above should reveal more about what is really happening here.

Comment: It is a bit weird, I checked and the files are tracked, I restarted Visual Studio (because it frozen) and know it seems to work but I am not very confident about it. Thank you anyway @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Then this sounds like some kinky Visual Studio thing where the local files are not being updated.  Or possibly, the old versions are overwriting what Git swaps before they can be loaded.  In any case, whenever you hit a snag like this, fall back to the bash and use `git status`, because it seldom leads you astray.

Comment: Yes, it seems, I will do it because I have being doing some tests and I think that Git with Visual Studio works better from the Git console, maybe some kind of cache. Thank you